# create report from node and users

Tags: drupal-6, view, taxonomy

hi 
how to create report from user for example

display number of node create by user on day, week & month
display time activity of user on day, week & month

display number of create node by all user on day, week & month

Answer (score 0):

Most if not all of that can be accomplished using [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views). If you are not familiar with Views, then you should search online for any screencasts and tutorials you can find (http://www.drupalove.com/drupal-video-categories/views).

You may also want to take a look at this module. http://drupal.org/project/total_control

Comment: i create views page but my problem is i don't know how to show number of post and activity